# Invalid message not assoiciated to field

Tags: php, validation, symfony, error-handling, symfony-2.5

I am in need to displaying an error when two passwords fields are mismatching. I am trying to achieve this through setting `invalid_message` in my `repeated` `password` field, But when I try to call the error as `{{form_errors(form.password)}}` the error does not appear. However if I use `{{form_errors(form)}}` the the password mismatch error appears. I need to make the error field specific and would greatly value your input on this :)

I tried many online searches but none helped. Following is my implementation,

- the `twig`

  ```
            {{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'form-horizontal', 'role': 'form', 'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}
              <!--just placed the error here for debug purposes-->
              {{ form_errors(form) }}  
              <div class="form-group {% if form.email.vars.errors|length > 0 %}has-error{% endif %} {% if form.email.vars.required == 'true' %}required{% endif %}">
               {{ form_label(form.email) }} 
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  {{ form_widget(form.email) }}
                  <span class="help-block">{{ form_errors(form.email) }}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group {% if form.password.vars.errors|length > 0 %}has-error{% endif %} {% if form.password.vars.required == 'true' %}required{% endif %}">
                {{ form_label(form.password.first) }}
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  {{ form_widget(form.password.first) }}

                </div>              
              </div>
              <div class="form-group required">
                {{ form_label(form.password.second) }}
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  {{ form_widget(form.password.second) }}
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="center-block btn-sign-in">
                 {{ form_widget(form.submit) }}
                </div>
              </div>
              <span class="form-footer-msg">Already have an account? <a href="/signin">Sign In</a></span>
            {{ form_end(form) }}
  ```

  - the `form`

    ```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

      $builder->add('email', 'email', array('label'=>'Email', 
                                            'attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control'), 
                                            'required'=>true,
                                            'trim' => true,
                                            'data'=>'user1@test.com',
                                            'label_attr'=>array('class'=>'col-sm-3 control-label')));

      $builder->add( 'password', 'repeated', array( 'type' => 'password', 
                                            //here is the password mismatch error message
                                            'invalid_message' => ErrorMessages::PASSWORDS_DONOT_MATCH,
                                            'options' => array('attr' => array('class' => 'password-field form-control')),
                                            'error_bubbling' => true,
                                            'required' => true,
                                            'trim' => true,
                                            'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Password',
                                                                      'error_bubbling' => true,
                                                                      'label_attr'=>array('class'=>'col-sm-3 control-label')),
                                            'second_options' => array('label' => 'Confirm password',
                                                                      'error_bubbling' => true,
                                                                      'label_attr'=>array('class'=>'col-sm-3 control-label'))));            

      $builder->add('submit', 'submit', array('label'=>'Create Account', 
                                              'attr'=>array('class'=>'btn btn-primary'))) 
              ->setMethod('POST')
              ->getForm();
    }

    public function getName() {

      return 'signup';
    }
    ```
  - the `controller`

    ```
    public function indexAction() {
      $signUp = new User();

      $form = $this->createForm(new SignUpForm(), $signUp, 
        array('action'=>$this->generateUrl('accounts_signup')));

      $request = $this->get('request');
      $form->handleRequest($request);

      if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

        if ($form->isValid()) {

          $request  = $this->get("request");
          //do something
        }else{
          //do something else
        }
      }

      return $this->render('AccountsBundle:Signup:index.html.twig', 
        array('form'=>$form->createView()));
    }
    ```

Your input on this matter is greatly appreciated sirs :) thank you very much :)

Comment: Why do you have error_bubbling = true in your password element?

Comment: @Cerad it was suggested here : http://www.99bugs.com/symfony-2-repeated-field-shows-blank-errors/ that enabling `error_bubbling` will allow to display `invalid_message` on repeated field on a form :)

Comment: I would call that a bad suggestion.

Comment: @Cerad okey i ll check your answer and post back :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error bubbling is not needed.  Here is a working example:

```
    $builder->add('password', 'repeated', array(
        'type'     => 'password',
        'label'    => 'Zayso Password',
        'required' => true,
        'attr'     => array('size' => 20),

        'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.',
        'constraints'     => new NotBlankConstraint($constraintOptions),

        'first_options'   => array('label' => 'Zayso Password'),
        'second_options'  => array('label' => 'Zayso Password(confirm)'),

        'first_name'  => 'pass1',
        'second_name' => 'pass2',
    ));

# twig
{{ form_row(form.password.pass1) }}
{{ form_row(form.password.pass2) }}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer.. but if I apply this there is rendering issue that I come across.. notice the `<div class="form-group {% if form.password.vars.errors|length > 0 %}has-error{% endif %} {% if form.password.vars.required == 'true' %}required{% endif %}">` This doesnt properly get executed. for that to properly function I have to use `form_widget` instead of `form_row`. and if i use `form_widget` it doesnt render the error messages. DO you know a way to render the errors for the `form_widget`?

Comment: form_errors(form.password.first) should do the trick.  Get the basic functionality working then go back and add your class code.